# UIButton with @IBinspectable for localization in Swift/Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, uibutton, extension-methods

I am trying to make an extension for all UIButton subclasses that will allow me to type a key into the Xcode UIBuilder, and have it automatically change that key into the appropriate language in real build time.

It works well when I run the app but the keyword I type in in the builder is not localized in the UI.

I tried using #if builder statements and prepareForInterfaceBuilder(). 
This is what I got so far:

```
extension UIButton {
 @IBInspectable var localizedText: String {
     set (key) {
         self.setTitle(key.localized, for: .normal)
     }
     get {
         return (self.titleLabel?.text)!
     }
   }
 }
```

and

```
class Button: UIButton {
.
.
.
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.titleLabel?.text = localizedText
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension...

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var localizedTitle: String {
        get { return "" }
        set {
            self.setTitle(newValue.localized, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var localized: String {
        get { return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "") }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say .localized is a string extension that calls NSLocalizedString on itself and returns the result.
The only difference between our code is that you return "" and you use newValue as a variable.
I am trying to use the value set in the builder as the newValue.

Comment: So your string extension is not working here??? Because i have been using this, it's working so far for me..

Comment: I have updated the answer with string extension... I also tested it before posting...

Comment: yes, it's the same as my version.
When you say work, can you change the @IB-value in the UI-view to "hello" and have it graphicly show up as "holla" (if translating to spaninsh). 
For me I only see "hello" untill i run the app.

The paoint is that

Comment: Yes brother that's exactly what i tested... If it's not working for you I'm sure something is wrong with your localised translations....... try this `print(NSLocalizedString("hello", comment: ""))` just to double check if your localisation string are fine.